# Slow PHP Perfomance on Qualified Server

Tags: php, windows, server, windows-server-2012-r2

I noticed that PHP is showing very slow performance on a very qualified server.

I use those code below to test PHP:

```
$x=0; for ($i=0 ; $i < 100000 ; $i++) { $x++; }
```

Time measurements are:
- **0.0700 - 0.0800** second on our server,
- **0.0280 - 0.0300** second on my ordinary laptop,
- **0.0060 - 0.0070** second on a website hosting server,

But I noticed that sometimes our server complete it
- *0.0300-0.0350 second very rarely*

Our virtual server is build on:
*Windows Server 2012 r2 x7560 @ 2.27GHz, 32 GB Ram, 32 Cores*

PHP is running with WAMP server:
- *WAMP Server 64 bit (3.0.6)*
- *PHP version is 5.6.26*

**What is causing that slowness?**

Comment: You virtual server is competing for resources.

Comment: Try to measure time with `getrusage()`, which should give you the time PHP is actually executing code. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getrusage.php (use a considerably longer period to measure acurrately!)